# How to send data multiple same name input using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a poll system for my project like facebook. But I need help in a matter. I use the following JavaScript code to increase the answers for inputs.

```
$("body").on("click",".createnew", function(){
      $(".inputsl").append("<div class='inputt'><input type='text' name='myanswer' id='createmyanswer' class='myinput' placeholder='Write answer!'></div>");
   });
```

When you click on the CreateNew button users can prompted to write a new answer.  Like this:

```
<div class="inputsl">
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer" class="myinput"></div>
</div>
```

So you can see all input name and id is same. It is easy to send one input value. But I want to give the user the right to ask more than one question.

For this I used the following ajax code.

```
$("body").on("click",".insertp", function(){
       var answers = $("#createmyanswer").val();
       var dataPollAnswers = 'answers=' + answers;
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/requests/postPollAnswers',
           data: dataPollAnswers,
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function(){},
           sucess: function(){
               console.log("Success!");
           }   
        });
     });
```

The last think is php codes for postPollAnswers. I have used the following php codes for sending all created answers.

```
<?php 
include_once '../inc/inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['answers'])){
    $answers = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['answers']);
    if($answers){
foreach($answers as  $setAnswer){
      $insertAnswersfromData = $InSert->Insert_Poll($uid, $setAnswer);
    }
    }
}
?>
```

I think i have array problem i have searched a solution and tryed many thinks but i can not send multiple answers. I have checked also maybe i need some jquery code like serialize() ect. and tryed but i can not get any result.

Also i am getting this warning:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Anyone can help me here please ?

Comment: You shouldn't use duplicate id's .. ever..

Comment: use name="myanswer[]"  and id should be unique .so use class name

Comment: Use array, like myanswer[]

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for more than one element, they are supposed to be used to identify a single HTML element, hence their name. I believe `$("#createmyanswer").val();` will only return the value of the first or last `#createmyanswer` element.

Comment: @DencyGB I am getting this warning: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @dogui yes you are right what should i do for it ?

Comment: @yezzz So What should id do to send ?

Comment: @JYoThI I have tryed your answer and i got this warning `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` from postPollAnswers

Comment: do something like this  dataPollAnswers  = $('.myinput').serialize();

Comment: Assuming your `.myinput` class is only used for the answer inputs that you want, you can make an array that maps over these inputs and gets each value, like so: `let answers = Array.from($('.myinput')).map(e => e.value)`.

Comment: @dogui i am not using a form.

Comment: @JYoThI `dataPollAnswers = $('.myinput').serialize();` will send values ?

Comment: yeah it will serialize() all the input

Comment: @JYoThI Yes i have tested, it is sending values with serialize(). So i need change some php code for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change selector to `class name` and use `serialize`

```
dataPollAnswers = $('.myinput').serialize();
```

Note : id should be unique

**Update 1:**

**PHP :**

```
foreach($_POST['myanswer'] as $row)
 {             ^^^^^^^^^^
    echo $row;
 }
```

Note : Input name is **`myanswer`** not **answer**

**Update 2:**

**PHP**

```
    <?php 
    include_once '../inc/inc.php';
    if(isset($_POST['myanswer'])){

            foreach($_POST['myanswer'] as  $setAnswer)
            {
              if(!empty($setAnswer))
              {
              $new_set_ans = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $setAnswer);
              $insertAnswersfromData = $InSert->Insert_Poll($uid, $new_set_ans);
               }
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So i need to change some php code to send for it from `postPollAnswers `

Comment: @jyothl because not saving any data.

Comment: take a look at my update 1 @DevStud . you need to access the data like this

Comment: i am checking it now.

Comment: So the input should be like this right ? `<input type="text" name="myanswer[]" id="createmyanswer" class="myinput" placeholder="Write answer!">`

Comment: so it send multiple now but there is a problem. Value is not set it looks like _NULL_ . My query is : `$query=mysqli_query($this->db, "INSERT INTO poll(answer)VALUES(answer='$new_set_ans')")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));`

Comment: take a look on my update 2 @DevStud   just check if(!empty($value)){ insert ....  }

Comment: Please look at this image [CLICK](https://scontent-otp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18403346_459454461054385_5933164982419116117_n.jpg?oh=c935d1eb6b01230be3f6cb28f14d6642&oe=59775BD9)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort dear it solved my problem. You taught me something new. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help you @DevStud

Answer (score 1):

just take name attribute as array and their id's should be unique:

```
 var i;

$("body").on("click",".createnew", function(){
      $(".inputsl").append("<div class='inputt'><input type='text' name='myanswer[]' id='createmyanswer'"+i+" class='myinput' placeholder='Write answer!'></div>");
     i++;//no needed if you dont want to use id attribute
   });
```

Then post as usual using name attribute and you will get array at server side .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is working demo for you:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var paramsToSend = {};
  var i = 1;
  $("input[name='myanswer[]']").each(function(){
    paramsToSend[i] = $(this).val();
    i++;
  });
  
   $("#dataToSend").html(JSON.stringify(paramsToSend));
   
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'URL_HERE',
         data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
         success: function(data) {
          console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
         }
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputsl">
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer[]" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer[]" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer[]" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createmyanswer" name="myanswer[]" class="myinput"></div>
</div>
<button id="submit">
Submit
</button>

<div id="dataToSend"></div>
```